# fasterxml jackson objectmapper convert string

Tags: java, jackson, json

my string is: json = {"foo":"bar"}{"foo":"bar"}

========================

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = null;
try { 
      final JsonParser jParser = mapper.getFactory().createParser(json);
      jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jParser);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      log.warn("Fail to parse the input json-string: ", e);
}
```

=========================

the jackson convert it to : jsonNode = {"foo":"bar"}

i want to catch this exception, but it do not throw any exception when it convert

Comment: 1) Is your json string really 2 objects or was it a copy paste error? 2) You are catching the exception and it wont throw any exception when it is converted... Your code looks fine for your requirements, are you looking for something different?

Comment: yes, my json is 2 object= '{"foo":"bar"}{"foo":"bar"} '.

Comment: i expect the jackson library will throw exception when input the above json string, but it not.

Comment: i tested some different ways, got the same result that no exception

Comment: Im sure theres a better way to do this but i did find that if you wrap your response in an array `[{"foo":"bar"}{"foo":"bar"}]` you will get an error. You could then get your node by doing `jsonNode.get(0)`. I looked around and couldnt find anything right away.

Comment: It looks like Jackson threats your json string containing two top-level JSON objects as a valid JSON. While the RFC 4627 says: "A JSON text is a serialized object or array." Could it be a Jackson bug? Any other opinions?

Comment: @Alexey Looks like it to me, after running some tests it seems like the parser finds the first root level entity and returns it and discards the rest of the input. Not sure if its bug or intentional. If I was to guess its intentional but there should be some documentation on it somewhere.

Comment: @ug_ it is fully intentional. Top-level sequence of JSON values is not considered an error, and ability read such is considered a feature. There has been discussion on JSON spec list of formalizing such usage because it is quite wide-spread for data analytics, hadoop style processing and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the same technique as in the answer to:
[How to detect trailing garbage using Jackson ObjectMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003171/how-to-detect-trailing-garbage-using-jackson-objectmapper)

There mapper.readValue was used but it should work similarly for mapper.readTree. That is, after passing your JsonParser to the mapper, check that jParser.nextToken() returns "null".