# How to detect trailing garbage using Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

Say I have a class

```
class A {
    public int x;
}
```

Then a valid json can be parsed as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
A a = mapper.readValue("{\"x\" : 3}", A.class);
```

Is there a way to have the parser fail if the string contains more data than necessary to parse the object?

For example I would like the following to fail (which succeeds)

```
A a = mapper.readValue("{\"x\" : 3} trailing garbage", A.class);
```

I tried it using an InputStream with JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE=false and checking whether the stream has been consumed completely, but that does not work:

```
A read(String s) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    JsonFactory f = new MappingJsonFactory();
    f.configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, false);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(f);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    try {
        A a = mapper.readValue(is, A.class);
        if(is.available() > 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        return a;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

that is,

```
read("{\"x\" : 3} trailing garbage");
```

still succeeds, probably because the parser consumes more from the stream than strictly necessary.

One solution that works is to verify that the parsing fails when dropping the last charachter from the string:

```
A read(String s) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    A a = mapper.readValue(s, A.class);

    if (s.length() > 0) {
        try {
            mapper.readValue(s.substring(0, s.length()-1), A.class);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

but I'm looking for a more efficient solution.

Comment: did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main thing to do is to create a `JsonParser` first, separately, then call `ObjectMapper.readValue()` passing that parser, and THEN call `nextToken()` once more and verify it returns null (instead of non-null value, or throw exception).

So, something like

```
try(JsonParser jp = mapper.getFactory().createParser(jsonSource)) {
    Value v = mapper.readValue(jp, Value.class);
    if (jp.nextToken() != null) {
        //throw some exception: trailing garbage detected
    }
    return v;
}
```

---

Note: This is for Jackson 2.x. For Jackson 1.x, use `getJsonFactory().createJsonParser()` instead of `getFactory().createParser()`.

Answer (score 13):

As of Jackson version 2.9, there is now DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS which can be used to achieve that:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper =
        new ObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS);
```

See
 https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9 and
https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/jackson-2-9-features-b2a19029e9ff

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like below.
Basically loop through the tokens before you `readValue`.
[JsonParser#nextToken()](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser.html#nextToken%28%29) validates if your String is a proper JSON.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, IOException  {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String str = "{\"x\" : 3} garbage";

        JsonParser x = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(str);
        while(x.nextToken()!=null){

        }
    A a =   mapper.readValue(str, A.class);

        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('g' (code 103)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@65faba46; line: 1, column: 12]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1432)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._handleUnexpectedValue(ReaderBasedParser.java:1192)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedParser.java:479)
    at example.JsonParse.main(JsonParse.java:21)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works indeed. I accepted the other answer which uses the same technique but only needs to scan the input once.